# Unable to create service java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android tutorial that creates an odometer service:           https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid/tree/master/chapter13/Odometer

It appears I need to explicitly ask the user for permissions to use the location services.
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

But this seems to be for activities extending ActivityCompat.  My MainActivity extends Activity.

Does anyone have an example of how to implement requestPermissions() when extending the Activity class?  And where exactly would it go...in it's on class or in onCreate?

Thanks

Comment: `Activity` has `requestPermissions` method ...

Answer (score 0):

`ContextCompat` is public class derived from android.support.v4 library and it's not related to the AppCompatActivity. For checking permission on Android version 23 and up you would do something like this:

```
private void getPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(test_activity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(test_activity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + permission + " is already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }
```

than call the method in `onCreate`:

`getPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, requestCode);`

Than override `onRequestPermissionsResult` and handle the result:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    switch (requestCode) {
        //Location
        case 1:
            // do something
            break;
    }
  else
 {
 Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```